# BlockingCollection Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I have a program in which i am getting bitmap images from Camera loading them in 
blocking collection and processing in a thread. I am calling SetImage from UI thread.
It works for few seconds then i run into out of memory exception. Please advise

```
Class MyThread
{
   BlockingCollection<Bitmap> q = new BlockingCollection<Bitmap>();

   Thread thread;

   public MyThread()
   {

     thread = new Thread(ThreadFunc);
     thread.Start();
   }

   void ThreadFunc()
   {
     Bitmap local_bitmap = null;

     while (!exit_flag)
     {
        // This blocks until an item appears in the queue.
        local_bitmap = q.Take();

        // process local_bitmap
     }
   }

   public void SetImage(Bitmap bm)
   {
        q.Add(bm);
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the search, dispose the bitmap.

Comment: Beyond forgetting to dispose the bitmaps, you'll always get this exception when the camera spits out bitmaps faster than you can process them.  Which is a very likely mishap.  The point of a BlockingCollection is to let it block when it gets full.  Use the constructor that takes an *int*.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant for your input. This is precisely the case with me my camera is giving images faster than i can process them. Are you suggesting me to use a bounded collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose the Bitmap object in  your code as it contains managed resources,  the thread func should be:

```
void ThreadFunc()
   {


     while (!exit_flag)
     {
        // This blocks until an item appears in the queue.
        using (Bitmap local_bitmap = q.Take())
        {

        // process local_bitmap
        }
     }
   }
```

GC is designed to manage memory automatically, but as when to schedule GC, the runtime takes into account how much managed memory is allocated, not the unmanaged memory usage. So in this case, you need dispose the object by your self or call GC.AddMemoryPressure to speeding the GC.